# How to change grub-bios to grub-efi

Tags: dual-boot, apple, grub-efi

So a while ago I installed Ubuntu on my MacBook. I had to reinstall it because something in the update manager messed up. Not to concerned about that but for some reason after the installation Ubuntu won't boot.

I found out later that Apple hardware uses EFI as its firmware (BIOS is the wrong term). Every time I try to install it I make a swap space and the root file to make the installation. I noticed that when I make the boot file its in grub-bios. I need to change this to grub-efi. I found out but there is no option to change this. It still won't boot though. When I install it I don't get any errors but doing a little bit of reasearch I find that the boot file may be the problem.

How to fix this?

Comment: Please indicate your [Boot-Info URL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info).

Comment: Please add your CPU architecture ( 32 or 64 bits  )

Answer (score 0):

Using `apt-get` or GUI tools to install the `grub-efi` package should cause the package system to replace `grub-pc` (the BIOS/legacy GRUB) with the EFI-mode GRUB. Beyond that, it's not clear to me what you mean by several comments in your question:

- "When i install it i dont get any errors" (what do you mean by "it"? The `grub-efi` package?)
- "It still wont boot though" (what won't boot, GRUB, Linux, OS X, or something else? What sort of error conditions do you get -- a blank screen, an error message, a boot logo that never disappears, etc.?)
- "The boot file may be the problem" (to what "boot file" are you referring?)

Stepping back a bit, the most popular dual-boot configuration for Ubuntu and OS X uses [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/) as a boot manager to select which OS to boot along with the BIOS version of GRUB to launch Linux. Substituting the EFI version of GRUB is desirable, IMHO. Even better, at least with 3.3.0 and later kernels (included in Ubuntu 12.10), is to use the kernel's own EFI stub loader. This can be facilitated by use of [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) as a boot manager. rEFInd is a fork of rEFIt (which hasn't been updated in over two years); rEFInd fixes bugs and adds new features, particularly related to booting Linux. The rEFInd Web page includes detailed documentation on using it to boot Linux. You can use it much like rEFIt (to chainload either the BIOS-mode or EFI-mode GRUB) or you can use it to launch a Linux kernel with EFI stub loader support, thus bypassing GRUB.